# Conditional type with inference and extends clause on TS 4.6

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following types with TS 4.7 in mind :

```
const routes = {
  foo: '/foo/:paramFoo',
  bar: '/bar/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
  baz: '/baz/baz2/:paramFoo/:paramBar',
} as const;

type Routes = typeof routes;

type RouteParser<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string[] :
  S extends '' ? [] :
  S extends `${infer T}/:${infer U}` ? [T, ...RouteParser<U>] : [S]; 

type RouteParams<S extends string> = RouteParser<S> extends [infer path, ...infer params extends string[]] ? { // can't do that in TS 4.6 
  [K in params[number]]: string;
} : { [x in string]: string; };


function navigateTo<T extends keyof Routes, U extends Routes[T]>(route: U, params: RouteParams<U>) {
  let actualRoute: string = route;
  Object.keys(params ?? {}).forEach((param) => {
    actualRoute = actualRoute.replace(`:${param}`, param in params ? params[param] : '');
  })

  console.log(actualRoute);
}



navigateTo(routes.foo, { paramFoo: 'foo' })
navigateTo(routes.bar, { paramFoo: 'foo', paramBar: 'bar' })
navigateTo(routes.baz, { paramFoo: 'foo', paramBar: 'bar' })
navigateTo(routes.baz, { paramFoo: 'foo', paramBar: 'bar' })
```

I am currently stuck on an Angular 13 project though, and I can't use the `extends` clause feature brought by TS 4.7

How could I rewrite it to work with TS 4.6 ?

[Playground (using version 4.6)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#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-cEyAar6pxnPaeCLZLwbjabzSB-dEEAtmQdxinWphiPQsxNgQ34mmaKAWgByRARIoG7rIFDUFBW4yFYYgSNBF74HBv6If+eZoPcmjoeBZCQbwuFKKI1CEeesFGvBf7IcE1H6LRFgQdhjEYfhrEqOxaoEDQNAwAAAlAEAALSFL42oqXACBwBxP4IUhlGofoxFAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4.6, we would write the following:

```
type RouteParams<S extends string> = RouteParser<S> extends [infer path, ...infer params] ? params extends string[] ? {
  [K in params[number]]: string;
} : { [x in string]: string; } : { [x in string]: string; };
```

Which is why we have the new extends in infer clauses in 4.7.

You have to move the `params extends string[]` into its own conditional.